# Allow ASP controls in a table to stack

Tags: asp.net, formatting, xmltable

I have run across an issue I have no idea if it's possible to fix because I have no idea what to search for to see if this solution is out there somewhere :)

For ease in formatting my controls on the web application, I've created the controls in a table, and it works great except for this one small flaw.  If I create one textbox within a table cell under a table row(row1), it works fine.  but if I create a table row again underneath row1, and try to create two labels and textboxes to appear directly below row1's label and textbox there seems to be an issue and looks like the second label/textbox won't appear until after the row1's textbox has ended.

A Pic is attached for further explanation

[image]

Here is the `table` code

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
            <asp:TableRow runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <asp:Label runat="server">Test label
                    </asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1" Columns="35">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <asp:Label runat="server">
                        Test label2
                    </asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt2" Columns="15">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:Label runat="server">
                      Test label 3
                    </asp:Label>
                </asp:TableCell>
               <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt3![enter image description here][2]" Columns="5">
                </asp:TextBox>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
      </asp:Table>
```

Is this possible to get these two(label2 and 3 + textboxes) to be adjacent to each other while being direcly under the textbox in row1?

Comment: Add a `ColumnSpan="3"` to the cell of the first textbox?

Comment: I doubt you will need to access table properties at the server side. If this is so, forget about `asp:Table`/`asp:TableRow`/`asp:TableCell` and use `table`/`tr`/`td` instead. The markup will become much more readable.